# How to assign line number to a variable in a while loop

Tags: shell, awk, while-loop

I have a file contains some lines. Now I want to read the lines and get the line numbers. As below:

```
while read line
do
string=$line
number=`awk '{print NR}'`  # This way is not right, gets all the line numbers.
done
```

---

Here is my scenario: I have one file, contains some lines, such as below:

```
2015Y7M3D0H0Mi44S7941
2015Y7M3D22H24Mi3S7927
2015Y7M3D21H28Mi21S5001
```

I want to read each line of this file, print out the last characters starts with "S" and the line number of it. it shoud looks like:

```
1  S7941
2  S7927
3  S5001
```

So, what should I properly do to get this?

Thanks.

Can anyone help me out ???

Comment: It's a wonder this doesn't hang, `awk '{ print NR }'` is not a valid awk script without an input file. You should print out a variable which you increase every iteration.

Comment: perhaps I could use a variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UNIX shell is simply an environment from which to call tools and a language to sequence those calls. The UNIX general purpose text processing tool is awk so just use it:

```
$ awk '{sub(/.*S/,NR" S")}1' file
1 S7941
2 S7927
3 S5001
```

If you're going to be doing any text manipulation, get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: I find it works, and seems to be more professional. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I just asked one of my friend, Found a simple way:

```
cat -n $file |while read line
do
   number=echo $line | cut -d " " -f 1
   echo $number
done
```

That means if we can not get line number from the file itself, we pass it with a line number.

Comment: No. No, no, no. Whatever it is you are really trying to do, that is an awful "solution" in every possible way. It is syntactically incorrect, massively inefficient, and will mangle the input lines in several different ways given various contents of the input file. Do NOT do this and find friends who have a little shell experience to ask shell questions! What you are asking for help with makes no sense to do - edit your question to explain the bigger picture of what you are trying to do and provide sample input/output so we can help you.